# Visual Studio 2010 Database project: Reference external database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-schema

I created a Database project by importing a schema from an existing database. In the project I am creating stored procedures that merge data with another database... My issue is that I get a ton of Warnings on the data from the referenced database. Below I will include screenshots and the offending procedure

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetContact]
    @ContactID [int]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        FirstName = COALESCE(a.FirstName, b.first_name),
        LastName = COALESCE(a.LastName, b.last_name),
        Organization = COALESCE(a.Organization, b.company),
        LanguageTypeID = COALESCE(a.LanguageTypeID, (CASE WHEN b.default_language = 'Spanish' THEN 3 ELSE 2 END))
    FROM [dbo].[Contact] AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN [OldDB].[dbo].[contacts] AS b
    ON a.ContactID = b.contact_identification_number
    WHERE a.ContactID = @ContactID

END
```

**Visual Studio**

*Schema Explorer*

[image]

*Error List*

[image]

```
Warning 12  SQL04151: Procedure: [dbo].[GetContact] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[Contact].[b]::[Default_Language], [*].[dbo].[Students].[b]::[Default_Language] or [*].[dbo].[Students].[Default_Language]. c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\TED\TED\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Programmability\Stored Procedures\dbo.GetContact.proc.sql   21  52  TED
```

Any thoughts as to how I can reference another schema to get rid of these warnings so I can focus on real issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database project doesn't know the the other databases of you server like "OldDB". You should define a Database Cross Reference in the Project Properties.
See the explanation here: http://publicityson.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-database-project-cross-database.html

Comment: This appears to not work after VS 2010.  Now a dbschema is not (AFAIK) supported; only a DACPAC.  I was able to create the former, but not the latter.  :(